# Flyway 5.0.7 non-transactional migrations MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, flyway

I'm using flyway 5.0.7 with MS SQL. I would like to turn on full text search on the server via flyway migrations. Problem is that all migrations are wrapped in transactions and its impossible to create fts catalog and index inside user transactions.

Question is: Is it possible to mark manually migration that it should not be executed in transaction?

I've tried to set mixed option to "true" - no results

I've tried to do some tricks with `sp_executesql CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ..` inside stored procedure and execute this stored procedure in migration. But without any affects

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2242) which has been fixed but is not in a release yet. It will be in Flyway 6.0.0 whenever that is released.

In the meantime, you could try the [Flyway 6.0.0-beta release](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/releases)

> Question is: Is it possible to mark manually migration that it should not be executed in transaction?

I've had a quick look at the [code](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/37211a828ebc3913fa828a655bbac57e067c0ec0/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/sqlserver/SQLServerSqlStatementBuilder.java#L72-L77) but I can't see a way to override the [regex](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/37211a828ebc3913fa828a655bbac57e067c0ec0/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/sqlserver/SQLServerSqlStatementBuilder.java#L42-L47) without a code change.

Comment: I've made a workaround, after flyway finish all migrations I'm executing script from command line with using sqlcmd. In this script I'm creating full text search catalog and index